# Intel XDK 3240 - No build target activated

Tags: intel-xdk

I'm using Intel XDK tool version 3240. Here, i could not set build target. I need to know what is **NO BUILD TARGET ACTIVATED** and to set the target. How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting one of the build targets in project settings, if selected, it should be in blue like this:

[image]